# How to select oldest record from sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

So I have a table of different appraisals saved for a lot of different vehicles and I want to select all appraisals with specific appraisal type but there can be more than 1 entries for the specific record id with that type and I only want to select the oldest

So I have this query (results below)

```
select

p.seller_opportunity_id
, p.created_at
, p.created_by
, p.type
, p.pricing_output_quote3_rounded_list_price_usd

    from
      frunk.pricing_events as p
      inner join database.opportunity o
    inner join database.vehicle_c v on
      o.vehicle_id_c = v.id on
        p.seller_opportunity_id = o.id
    where
      o.auto_reject_c is false
      and o.stage_name not in (
        'Lost'
        , 'Sold'
        , 'Handover'
      )
     -- and p.type = 'appraisal-escalated'
      and o.id = 'id'
    order by
      p.created_at desc
```

Which results in this

[Image URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aLMX.png)

I want to create a nested query where I can get the `pricing_output_quote3_rounded_list_price_usd` for one `seller_opportunity_id` both from the type `appraisal-escalated` and `manual-quote` with the values of first records (there can be several as shown on screenshot)

Please note that the o.id where clause is for example sake and in the actual query I'd be querying the whole table with all the ids so adding 
`where p.created_at = (select min(p.created_at) from frunk)` would not work

Comment: share sample data with us

Comment: @Simonare updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ranking function like `dense_rank`.

```
select *
from (select p.*
            ,dense_rank() over(partition by seller_opportunity_id order by created_at) as rnk
      from appraisals 
      where type = 'appraisal-escalated'
     ) t
where rnk = 1
```

Read more about the function in the [`documentation`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_DENSE_RANK.html)

Comment: if two appraisals of the requested type are created at same time; this will return two records with rank 1; Not a problem but as we don't know how the original poster want to handle ties; just wanted them to be aware

Comment: yes..it will...unless a column is specified which can break ties in that case.